# Is there any performance impact when calling require inside a function?

Tags: node.js

Is there any performance impact by doing this:

```
// utils.js
module.exports = function() {/* do something */};

// then use it like this

function someTask(param) {
   /* do something with param */
   return require('./utils')(param);
}
```

Is it just a bad practice or there is any performance difference?

Comment: This is a good and valid question. Ignore whoever downvoted you and voted to close. It's not off topic. People here are just generally grumpy and pedantic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. When you require something it stores the result of that require on `require.cache` with the key being the full path to your module. Subsequent calls to require will simply return the cached module.

If you need to remove the module from the cache for some reason you can do it like this:

```
delete require.cache[require.resolve('./utils')];
```

`require.resolve` returns the full path of the module which is what the key is on the cache. After you clear the module from the cache then the next call to `require` would again pull the module from disc.

Generally it's probably good practice to do your requires at the top of the file for readability's sake, but other than the tiny bit of logic involved with returning the module from the cache I see no reason to consider it a performance issue.